# ¿Cómo graficar múltiples líneas con ggplot con eje X como variable de tiempo? (ver ejemplo)

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-dplyr

Preliminar:

Antes que nada, me disculpo por no subir mi código completo ya que es un poco largo y desconozco cómo subir un archivo aquí. Si alguien sabe, por favor oriénteme para poder actualizar mi pregunta.

Descargué de este sitio web un archivo de Excel:

```
datosabiertos.segob.gob.mx/DatosAbiertos/sesnsp_Incidencia_delictiva_Fuero_Federal/IDEFF
```

Lo guardé como csv y después de múltiples manipulaciones a la base de datos tengo esto:

```
> head(d1217full)
   año     mes comercio contra la salud narcomenudeo otros otros_lfcd otros_lgs transporte posesion produccion trafico total
1 2012   enero     0.16               0         5.87  0.13       0.02      0.00       0.02     4.34       0.07       0 10.61
2 2012 febrero     0.04               0         5.30  0.13       0.02      0.00       0.00     4.68       0.02       0 10.19
3 2012   marzo     0.07               0         4.81  0.07       0.05      0.00       0.00     6.12       0.07       0 11.21
4 2012   abril     0.40               0         4.48  0.13       0.04      0.00       0.00     4.85       0.00       0  9.90
5 2012    mayo     0.36               0         5.91  0.36       0.07      0.00       0.02     1.95       0.05       0  8.73
6 2012   junio     0.26               0         5.30  0.15       0.22      1.48       0.02     2.17       0.00       0  9.59
```

Al aplicar `str` tenemos:

```
> str(d1217full)
'data.frame':   72 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ año            : Factor w/ 6 levels "2012","2013",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ mes            : Factor w/ 12 levels "enero","febrero",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ comercio       : num  0.16 0.04 0.07 0.4 0.36 0.26 0.09 0.04 0.04 0.05 ...
 $ contra la salud: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.02 ...
 $ narcomenudeo   : num  5.87 5.3 4.81 4.48 5.91 5.3 4.27 6.6 6.29 9.84 ...
 $ otros          : num  0.13 0.13 0.07 0.13 0.36 0.15 0.13 0.09 0.02 0.09 ...
 $ otros_lfcd     : num  0.02 0.02 0.05 0.04 0.07 0.22 0.11 0.11 0.13 0.11 ...
 $ otros_lgs      : num  0 0 0 0 0 1.48 4.12 0.2 0.46 0.51 ...
 $ transporte     : num  0.02 0 0 0 0.02 0.02 0 0.02 0.02 0.02 ...
 $ posesion       : num  4.34 4.68 6.12 4.85 1.95 2.17 2.11 1.91 1.71 1.73 ...
 $ produccion     : num  0.07 0.02 0.07 0 0.05 0 0.02 0 0 0 ...
 $ trafico        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ total          : num  10.61 10.19 11.21 9.9 8.73 ...
```

Lo que deseo es poder hacer un gráfico que tenga las siguientes características:

1. En el eje x se registre el año y el mes desde 2012/01 hasta 2017/12
2. En el eje y se muestren, con diferentes líneas, los datos de las variables comercio hasta total, es decir, un total de 11 líneas, enfatizando en "total"

Dado que mis variables de tiempo son factores, `ggplot` no me permite graficar adecuadamente. Por ejemplo,

```
ggplot(d1217full, aes(año, total)) +
geom_line()
```

Da como resultado este plot, que por supuesto, es erróneo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo anterior, sin considerar que aún faltaría poder incluir el resto de variables en el plot.

Pensé en crear un vector de tiempo desde cero, incorporarlo a mi base de datos y luego hacer un gráfico siguiendo algo como:

```
añosgto <- c(seq(as.Date("2012/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 72))
añosgto <- as.character(añosgto)
temp  <- strsplit(añosgto, "-")
temp <- matrix(unlist(temp), ncol=3, byrow=T)
temp <- as.data.frame(temp)
temp <- mutate(temp, año_def=V1, mes_def=V2)
temp <- temp[,-(1:3)]
head(temp)

D1217 <- cbind(d1217full, temp)
D1217 <- select(D1217, -(1:2))

ggplot(D1217, aes(str_c(año_def, "/", str_pad(mes_def, 2, pad = 0)),
  total, group=total)) +
  geom_line() +
   scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("2012/12", "2013/12", "2014/12", "2015/12", "2016/12", "2017/12"))
```

Lo que da como resultado esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podrán ver, he intentado graficar sin éxito así que cualquier orientación será muy apreciada.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Cree un repositorio en github donde se encuentra la base de datos y el código.

https://github.com/LuisAlejandroCG/proyecto_gto

Comment: Estas buscando algo como esto: `ggplot(data=d1217full, aes(x=paste0(año,"/",mes), y=total)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")`?

Comment: Más o menos, pero que el eje X pueda verse en escala discreta como en el ejemplo que puse al final y que se pudieran incluir múltiples líneas para todas las variables numéricas ¿Te molestaría si te envío mi archivo por correo electrónico o por algún otro medio para que analices el código? Si tienes tiempo, claro está... Saludos y gracias, como siempre.

Comment: El resultado que deseo es parecido al de esta imagen: con X siendo los períodos discretos de tiempo y con la y siendo las variables numéricas. Puse ya la liga a un repositorio donde viene todo el código que tengo hasta el momento. ¡Saludos! https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkaZR.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya que estás usando `dplyr` aprovechemoslo al máximo:

```
d1217full %>%
    mutate(order = paste0(as.character(año), "-",sprintf("%02d",which(meses %in% mes)))) %>%
    gather(variable, valor, -`año`, -mes, -order) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=order,y=valor,colour=variable, group=variable)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_x_discrete(breaks=unique(paste0(as.character(d1217full$año), "-12"))) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

El resultado:

Detalle:

- `mutate(order = paste0(año, "-",sprintf("%02d",which(meses %in% mes))))` para crear una columna nueva correspondiente al eje `x`, es más fácil así ya que `año` y `mes`son factores y complicaría un poco si lo usamos directamente.
- `gather(variable, valor, -`año`, -mes, -order)` con esto reorganizamos la estructura para tener observaciones para cada una de las columnas que luego `ggplot` tratará como variables y líneas independientes
- El resto del código es simplemente la configuración del plot, configuramos los valores de `x`, `y`, cuales serán los grupos u quién define el color, lo último es configurara la orientación vertical de las etiquetas de los ejes `x`
- Con `scale_x_discrete(breaks=unique(paste0(as.character(d1217full$año), "-12")))` definimos los cortes en el eje `x` para que estos sean siempre diciembre de cada año tal como mencionas en tus comentarios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Una última pregunta: ¿Como ajusto para que en el eje x salgan solo valores por intervalos? Intenté con scale_x_discrete pero no funciona. Te comento: utilizo los datos de todos los períodos porque la idea es mostrar cómo han disminuido los delitos en los últimos años, por eso mi insistencia en mostrar todo y de ahí también la insistencia de mostrar el eje x en intervalos discretos. Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: @AlejandroCarrera, ¿Como serían estos intervalos? Con respecto al gráfico, me da la impresión que tienes muchas variables a mostrar y con volúmenes muy diferentes, claramente totales, narcomenudeo, posesion y otros_lgs modifican mucho la escala y las otras variables quedan bien abajo en el eje y por lo que es imposible apreciar ninguna tendencia, asimismo hay variables con valores muy pequeños que se mantienen prácticamente estables. De todas formas si lo que quieres es ver tendencias tal vez este tipo de gráfica no sea el mejor, una regresión o `geom_smooth()`, tal vez.

Comment: Me refiero a que en el eje X sólo se vean las leyendas 2012/12, 2013/12 y así hasta 2017/12. Entiendo lo que comentas sobre los volúmenes, pero las variables se expresaron en tasa por 100 mil habitantes para hacerlas comparables. Sé que parece necedad, pero es parte de un proyecto que estoy haciendo en materia de seguridad; de ahí mi insistencia en algo tan específico. ¡Gracias!

Comment: @AlejandroCarrera, edité mi respuesta, y agregue `scale_x_discrete(breaks=unique(paste0(as.character(d1217full$año), "-12")))` para definir las leyendas o ticks del eje `x`, cualquier osa me dices.

Comment: Es justo lo que estaba buscando. Gracias por tu paciencia y tu ayuda. ¡Saludos!